# How to repair holes in exterior insulation at foundation

Tags: insulation, exterior

My dogs dug at the base of my home's exterior, digging out insulation in a couple of areas. What can I do to repair the holes in the insulation? Is there a spray I can use to fill the gaps, or do I have to pull the broken insulation out in sheets and put new sheets down?

They dug where the stucco ends, so initially dirt was just covering the pink foam insulation, and in one spot they dug clear through to the concrete foundation.

Comment: Best would be to replace small sections that are damaged with the same.  Cut a square hole and patch with a square piece.  Not sure if the spray foams will react with what you have now.

Comment: what are the dogs looking for, what are they smelling, or jus crazy

Answer (score 1):

You can fit back any pieces large enough to bother with and spray-foam to tie it together and fill in gaps. Just be sure to bury it again so the spray-foam is not exposed to sunlight for long.

If they've damaged quite a large area cutting in a sheet patch might be worth doing, but that's not required (or particularly beneficial) for a small damaged area.